# Is it a mitzvah to refine one's character?

Tags: mussar-ethics

We take it as a given that it's important to refine our character because we'll be a blessing to the people around us, commit fewer transgressions and perform more mitzvos. But do we have a source for the the mitzvah to refine our character?

One possibility is piru u'rivu, be fruitful and multiply. It's the very first commandment. If it only meant "reproduce a minimum amount" as it's usually interpreted, it would've sufficed to say rivu.

"Be fruitful" is something else. It means bear fruit. A soul's mission in this world to bear fruit. Call it love, service, creativity, healing... any deed you do that sustains and sweetens the world is a fruit on your tree, and you want to bear fruit as often as possible.

If refining character is a necessary to bear more fruit, then refining character is a mitzvah.

Thoughts?

Answer (score -4):

Rambam felt that refining character, morality, intellectually,  is the first mitzvah.

Comment: Where does he say that?

Comment: See Rambam Avot 5.7